# Querying JSON from C#

Tags: c#, json, linq

I'm trying to retreive a json item from a json string,this is my json for example:

```
{   
"users":{  
  "john":{  
     "password":"0506777031",
     "level":1
  },
  "doe":{  
     "password":"john",
     "level":1
  },
  "dasda":{  
     "password":"das",
     "level":"1"
  },
  "zuri":{  
     "password":"zuri123",
     "level":2
  }
 }
}
```

I use the json.net library,this is what i've tried so far:

```
 JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonstring); //this is thr string       
 JObject match = json["users"].Values<JObject>().Where(m => m["username"].Value<string>() == "itapi" && (m["password"].Value<string>() == "0506777031")).FirstOrDefault();
```

I'm getting an error on the second line.
   This is the error:

> Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong,i will appreciate any help! thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your question is "What am I doing wrong?", the answer would be

1. You are trying to typecast what is a JProperty into a JObject (JProperty has a property named **Value** you can access).
2. You are not traversing the JSON syntax tree properly.
3. There is no mention of the "username" within the JSON sample provided.

If the usernames in your example are the property keys (names) "john", "doe", "dasda" and "zuri"... The query you probably want is as follows:

```
var match = json["users"].Values<JProperty>().Where(m => m.Name == "doe" && m.Value["password"].ToString() == "john").FirstOrDefault();
```

EDIT: Alternatively, if the username is that key, you can use the direct lookup and assign to the variable match only if the password matches the one you are trying to compare. Also the following version will return the JObject and not the JProperty as it seems you originally wanted. This should also be more efficient.

```
JObject match;
var temp = json["users"]["doe"];
if(temp["password"].ToString() == "john")
{
    match = temp.ToObject<JObject>();
}
```

Comment: thanks!
now if i want to acess the "level" property of that match,how should it be done?
like this?
  `Console.WriteLine(match["level"]);`
because i'm getting another error haha @Jeremy Borg

Comment: @Slashy please see my updated answer. If using the first snippet, you would need to use match.Value["level"], if using the second you can directly use index notation since the JObject is now assigned to match so you can use match["level"].

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be using square brackets for "users"?

```
{   
    "users":[  
        "john":{  
        "password":"0506777031",
        "level":1
        },
        "doe":{  
        "password":"john",
        "level":1
        },
        "dasda":{  
        "password":"das",
        "level":"1"
        },
        "zuri":{  
        "password":"zuri123",
        "level":2
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It's not necessary, on json is very common to see objects implemented as properties, like the json posted by the user.

Comment: It's not an array, it's an object with multiple properties

Comment: @Gusman are you sure? Users looks like an array of user. Each user has level and password...

Comment: 100% sure, just look at the definition, it has braces so it's an object, so any entry "XXX" : "YYY" is a property on that object. its like if on C# you had an structure like this: *public class person{ public string password; public int level; } public class user{ public person john; public person doe; public person dasda; }* or more near to an anonymous type created on the fly: *new { john = new person(...), doe = new person(...) }*

Comment: @Gusman, I understand that, I think my point here is that he has written his json wrong.

Comment: @ragerory my json is validated here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
check this out :)

Comment: It depends, you aren't sure if the user has written the json or it comes from an external service, anyway it's usable and correct, so there's no need to change that structure.

Comment: @Gusman so you're on your way to write an proper answer? :P haha